# почему не видит фаил на javascript

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Подключаю статические ресурсы на страницу.

Стили css подключаются корректно, а скрипты на js не подключается, хотя в консоли никаких ошибок/предупреждений в отношении подключения js фаила нет.

Прилагаю изображения только относительно подключения статического ресурса [image: screen]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]
[image: screen4]
[image: screen5]

Comment: в консоли браузера? а в хтмл в браузере что?

Comment: Добавил изображения к изображению выше из вкладок браузера при запущенном приложении

Comment: так подключился, на скриншоте исходник js; какие признаки неполадок? а если брейкпоинт в начало скрипта поставить и срелоадить?